# How can I define offset for the anchor point google map api in this code

Tags: google-maps-api-3, anchor, infowindow

I want to move the info window outside of the marker. In this example infowindow is opened at the same point of the marker.

```
var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
                anchor.set("position",event.latLng);
                infoWindow.open(map,anchor);
```

Comment: What marker?  There is no marker in the posted code. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. BTW - a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) is a valid anchor for an InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

A [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) is a valid anchor for an InfoWindow.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infoWindow.setContent("some content");
infoWindow.open(map,marker);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/113d5bkk/1/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  infoWindow.setContent("some content");
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```